# Can this kind of SVG be simplified?

Tags: python, svg, graphics

I am having an SVG in a very complex format that is like this,

```
<svg>
    <clipPath id="clip2">  
        <path d="..."/>
    </clipPath>

    <clipPath id="clip3">  
        <path d="..."/>
    </clipPath>

    <clipPath id="clip4">  
        <path d="..."/>
    </clipPath>


    <linearGradient id="linear1" x1="..." x2="..." y1="..." y2="...">
        <stop offset="0.4375" style="stop-color:#abc"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <g clip-path="url(#clip2)" clip-rule="nonzero">
        <g clip-path="url(#clip3)" clip-rule="nonzero"> 
            <g clip-path="url(#clip4)" clip-rule="nonzero">
                <path d="..." style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero; fill:url(#linear1);"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <path d="..." style="..."/>
    <path d="..." style="..."/>
    <path d="..." style="..."/>
</svg>
```

Now, clearly as the linear gradient is having only one stop, it can be converted to a much simpler format. That is we can write the above *g within g within g* to simply a single path with the its fill stroke to be same as that of the single stop of corresponding gradient. I am trying to do this with a python script but still struggling on how to do it? I am new to this forum so help me If I am wrong somewhere. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: get rid of the gradient entirely and make the fill fill:#abc;

Comment: Yes that would surely simplify the gradient part. But how can we simplify the clip-path part?

Comment: Construct a path which is the intersection of the 3 paths, or put a clip-path on the clipPath element.

Comment: How can I know the intersection of the paths?

Comment: That's very hard to do with complete generality.

Comment: If you create a SVG file with the three paths (from the clipPaths), then load it into a vector editor (Inkscape, AI etc). you can use that to find the path that is the intersection of the three paths.  But doing it in a script is going to be a lot trickier, as Robert said.  You would need to find a Python library that knows how to intersect SVG paths.  I don't know of any.

Comment: By using this library [pyx](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/) I can have the intersection points. Still I am not sure how to proceed